# xamarin set switch position on page load iOS delay

Tags: forms, xamarin

We are using Xamarin to build a mobile app, on one page there is a switch, which we set depending on some different states within the app i.e. BT connected etc. When we run it on Android it's fine, but on the iOS version there a slight delay (<1sec) which means as the page loads and the user can see the switch move position.

I have tried different ways to set the switch before the page loads, but cannot find a way to set the switch before either the page loads or xaml start. I have added the add switch into the OnAppearing but still have this delay when loading the page and the user can see the switch moving.

Can any one advise how I can set the switch position to avoid seeing the switch move position and set it true or false before the user can see the switch and page.

```
       protected override void OnAppearing()
       {
        base.OnAppearing();
       

        SettingGrid.Children.Add(myswitch = new Xamarin.Forms.Switch()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            ThumbColor = Color.Red

        }, 4, 8);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried shared code in local site , but can not find the difference between them . Maybe you can share a gif file, then I will understand the effects your want.

> Can any one advise how I can set the switch position to avoid seeing the switch move position and set it true or false before the user can see the switch and page.

About this , you can add the `Switch` in `Xaml` or with coding previously ,not need to add it when `OnAppearing`.However you can modify the `myswitch.IsVisible` property when `OnAppearing` .Such as follow :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    myswitch.IsToggled = true;
    myswitch.IsVisible = true;
}
```

The **Xaml** code has added the `Switch` :

```
<Grid x:Name="MyLayout" >
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
        VerticalOptions="Start" 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Switch x:Name="myswitch" 
            VerticalOptions="Start" 
            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
            ThumbColor="Red" 
            Margin="4,8,0,0"/>
...
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is the video of the screen, when we switch screens there is a slight delay between of the colours and switches on the appear. I have tired to load in different ways via xmal and code. I am not sure sure how to avoid this switching, I am trying to set the switch position, colour etc before the page loads. So we set the colour to blue, switches are set to false etc then when the page loads all the setting is setup and there is no visible change to the user https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuABz32Tzxo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Brendon Thanks for sharing the video . Do you have a try with my shared solution ?

Comment: @Brendon I have tried in my local site , however not occurs the same phenomenon . Maybe there are some things be different with your project.